# Was asked to review a question that is more than 4 years old?

Tags: support, review

When reviewing the Close queue, I was asked (in earnest, not a test) about math.SE 987322, which is said to have been active last some 4 years back (?!). What is going on?

(The question is OK in my eyes, not rocket science but a reasonable question; perhaps homework/exercise though).

Comment: Notice that the question was recently bumped [by a new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987322/find-n-such-that-n-2-is-a-square-n-3-is-a-cube-and-n-5-a-fifth-power/3550230#3550230). The fact that the question was bumped makes more likely that it was noticed by some users (and got upvotes, downvotes, close votes depending on the users preference). Since the question indeed has a close vote, that is very likely what pushed it into the review queue - so it does not seem as a bug.

Comment: I'll add that [your review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1325230) and [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987322/find-n-such-that-n-2-is-a-square-n-3-is-a-cube-and-n-5-a-fifth-power#comment7300697_987322) have a later timestamp than the recently added answer.

Answer (score 7):

The question got a vote to close. Thus it was put in the review queue, so that others can express their view whether the question should be close or stay open.

The reason why it got a close-vote is, in all likelihood, what Martin said in a comment. The question got bumped to the frontpage by a new answer and thus got visibility. (The first vote to close came after the answer.)

More generally, it is not uncommon that old questions get votes to close and thus land in the review queue. Some users even look through old questions actively to see if there is something that should be closed. But this was not the case here I think.